# XHTML: Move CSS into every tag from the <style> header to a @style attribute like a "premailer" with XSLT, possible?

Tags: css, xslt, xhtml, premailer

On the Internet are several programs in e.g. Ruby or Python which move XHTML CSS styles into tags. They are often called premailer because some older mail programs have problems with header defined stylesheets. Here is a example what a python premailer does: [premailer on pypi](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/premailer/1.8)

What I want to do is to move the <strike>json formatted</strike> CSS stylesheets from the HTML `<style>` header inside every related node which has a `class` attribute.

Example input:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Sometest</title>

<style type="text/css">
/*<![CDATA[*/
ol{margin:0;padding:0}p{margin:0}.c1{vertical-align:top;width:93.6pt;border-style:solid}.c2{vertical-align:top;width:41.8pt;border-style:solid}hr.c1{page-break-before:always}
/*]]>*/
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div>
<p class="c1"><span>Style C2 Text</span></p>
<hr class="c1"/>
<p class="c2">Style C1 Text</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My desired output. Look at `style` in `<hr>` and `<p>`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Sometest</title>

<style type="text/css">
/*<![CDATA[*/
ol{margin:0;padding:0}p{margin:0}.c1{vertical-align:top;width:93.6pt;border-style:solid}.c2{vertical-align:top;width:41.8pt;border-style:solid}hr.c1{page-break-before:always}
/*]]>*/
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div>
<p class="c1" style="vertical-align:top;width:93.6pt;border-style:solid"><span>Style C2 Text</span></p>
<hr class="c1" style="page-break-before:always"/>
<p class="c2" style="vertical-align:top;width:41.8pt;border-style:solid">Style C1 Text</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Has anybody done this with **XSLT** before?
Is this also possible with XSLT 1.0 ?

Comment: (a) It doesn't look like you have any json there; (b) XSLT is for manipulating XML, not text inside tags, so this is unlikely to be easy; (c) XSLT is turing complete so this is possible if you really insist on using XSLT; (d) why would you want to do this using XSLT?

Comment: @Marvin You are right. I thought CSS is json because they look very similar. I want to do this in XSLT because I want to keep my program portable. Currently I'm using python and every Premailer for python destroys my XHTML structure because they all use HTML soup parsers. The output of the XHTML structure is not the same as the input. Maybe later I will switch to Java for the front end.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than do this in XSLT, which is clunky, and no more portable than Python, I suggest you adapt whatever premailer you prefer to use a straight XML parser instead of a tag soup parser.

Depending on how the premailers work, it might even be possible to use their tag soup parser for a first pass, then just use a DOM or SAX parser for the annotation phase.